# IIS Service Unavailable when changing ASP.Net version

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

When I change the ASP.Net version of a web application in IIS 6 from ASP.Net 1.1 to 2.0. ALL sites in IIS are becoming "unavailable" (Service Unavailable) for a brief moment (the time it takes to apply the changes in the IIS dialog).

I checked with Application Pools, but the sites are all in different application pools...

How can this be?

When I change the ASP.Net version of one application, this should not affect other applications does it?

Thanks in advance,

Remco

Comment: Btw: this happens when I apply ANY setting from the properties dialog in IIS... not just when changing ASP.Net setting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .Net tab in the IIS Manager is actually pretty dangerous - it will throw an IISReset at any change, and also sometimes just for spite :-)

[Scott Forsyth](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/default.aspx) has a blog article titled [ASP.NET tab in IIS, more dangerous than it first appears!](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2008/08/01/asp-net-tab-in-iis-more-dangerous-than-it-first-appears.aspx) that goes over the details.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can change the framework version outside of IIS to avoid this issue by using "Aspnet_regiis.exe". There is more information available here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1174765.aspx

Edit: Thanks to Christopher in the comments for letting me know that using this tool is the same as an IISReset and doesn't solve the issue. :(

Comment: Actually no - aspnet_regiis.exe causes AppDomain recycles on all application pools - the equivolent of an IISReset.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I modified my answer to reflect this info.

Answer (score 1):

Change master folder Virtual in upper dot net frame work and use in different Pool.You are not getting services unavailable.